# file being downloaded is too large in filesize

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I use the following code for downloading a excel file, it works but the file being downloaded is too large.

```cs
using (var wc2 = new WebClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    wc2.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
    // 
    //wc2.DownloadFileAsync(fileUri, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\demo\\" + fileName);

    wc2.DownloadFile("https://ds.postnord.com/v2/ptm/file/download/5184.22306", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\demo\\test.xls");
}
```

If I download the file using the browser it works fine, but not using the above code. But if I try downloading a jpg file from somewhere using the above code it works. What could possible be wrong here?

Comment: You are guessing the extension here, are you sure it's an `xls` file? What do you mean it's also too large?

Comment: That download link is real - it's an XLSX file and it's 695kb in size. Which isn't very big.

Comment: How do you know the file is "too large"? All you have told us about what goes wrong is summarized by "it works fine, but not using the above code". What's ***actually*** going wrong?

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is (in a properly installed/configured application) likely to resolve to write-protected directory, both in server and desktop-land. Most likely, you'll want to create a directory somewhere below `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` and save your junk in there. It's guaranteed to be writable.

Comment: Just ran the provided code and it downloaded the file - base64 encoded.Verified with https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: When I download the file using the code the file size is 927kb which is wrong and the file wont open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If Excel files downloaded using WebClient are corrupted:

You should add User-Agent header, accept headers and use accept encoding.

In addition, authorization is needed; otherwise, file downloaded will be read-only.

The following code will download your excel file without being corrupted or any other problems:

```
string Url = "https://ds.postnord.com/v2/ptm/file/download/5184.22306";
string accessToken = "" ;
WebClient c = new WebClient();

c.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/pdf, */*");
c.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
c.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
c.Headers["Authorization"] = accessToken;

c.DownloadFile(Url, @"c:\\downloaded6.xlsx");
```